# How to cycle back through parameters on a yasnippet?

Tags: yasnippet

When I got a snippet with a few parameters:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/${1:width}/${2:height}/${3:$$(yas-choose-value '("abstract" "city" "animals" "food" "people" "transport" "business" "sports" "technics"))}/${4:text}" alt="$3">
```

I can cycle forward pressing tab, but if I change my mind and want to modify a previous parameter the only way is leaving the cycle and go back by hand. Am I missing something or there's a key binding to go back?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing something or there's a key binding to go back?.

<kbd>S-<tab></kbd> should be bound to `yas-prev-field` (in `yas-keymap`) which takes you back.  Note that it had a bug until recently, where it always went back to the 1st field.  https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/722

Comment: Thank you!, the problem was that I had previously mapped `<backtab>` like this `(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<backtab>") 'yas-expand)` , and it was blocking the `S-<tab>`